# in Qt 4.8 how to set "Qt::PreciseTimer"

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

As the title says:
I have this snippet:

```
QTimer timerdata;
```

I can start the timer by calling `timerdata.start(5);` However, I am not getting 5 msec...I know that in Qt 5.x there are three levels of precision for timers:

- Qt::PreciseTimer: About 1 ms resolution on Windows
- Qt::CoarseTimer (default): About 15 ms resolution on Windows
- Qt::VeryCoarseTimer: 1000 ms resolution on all platforms

My question is is there something similar in qt 4.8 and if true, how to set it?

Comment: Did you try [`QObject::startTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#startTimer) + [`QObject::timerEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#timerEvent)? But maybe it's not more precise than QTimer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt4 does not provide high-precision timers. If you want high-precision timers, you need to either migrate to Qt5 or use another library.

For example, you could try this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/high_resolution_timer.html